# How to hide Next / Previous media key on Lock Screen in some devices?

Tags: android, tablet, lockscreen

I can show only play / pause button in phone device

```
mRemoteControlClientCompat.setTransportControlFlags(
            RemoteControlClient.FLAG_KEY_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
    if (info == null) {
        mRemoteControlClientCompat.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PAUSED);
        return;
    } else {
        mRemoteControlClientCompat.setPlaybackState(RemoteControlClient.PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
    }
```

This code from cast library : https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android

but in some devices, such as tablet : Xperia™ Z2 Tablet SOT21

it will show previous / next button, Do you know how to hide them ?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: oops, I created the duplicated issue.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721695/android-4-x-remotecontrolclient-settransportcontrolflags-not-working